# Taylor Series and Fourier Series Together

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, approximation

Suppose some function is approximated by a Taylor Series.  Then the Taylor Series is approximated by a Fourier Series, which would entail approximating each term in the Taylor Series by its own Fourier Series.  Then each term in each of the Fourier Series is approximated by a Taylor Series, and each of those terms by a Fourier Series, and the pattern is repeated indefinitely.

Obviously this would be a huge algebraic mess, but what would the result look like geometrically?  Would it resemble the original function?  Would it converge to a single, special geometry independent of the original function?  Would it matter if a Fourier Series was applied as the first step instead of a Taylor Series?

Comment: Taking a wild guess taylor of the fourier of the taylor of a function should give back taylor of the function

Comment: One difficulty: if you do not restrict to a finite interval (and for the Fourier series assume the function is periodic outside of that interval) the Fourier coefficients for the polynomial terms don't exist.  For instance, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \cos x \,\mathrm{d}x$ has no chance of converging.

Comment: There is an analogy between like decomposing a vector into basis when expanding fnction into series. When you write a taylor, you decompose the function into a poly one, and, in fourier, you decompose into a sine cosine one. Now, if you decompose a vector into one basis then decompose that decomposistion in another basis, you should still have the same vector